# xpath select text without childnode result

Tags: xpath, scrapy

html :

```
<h2 class="reward__pledge-amount">
Pledge $1 or more
    <div class="reward__currency-conversion">
        <h5 class="regular grey-dark">
             About <span>$1.00 USD</span>
        </h5>
    </div>
</h2>
<p class="reward__backer-count">
    <span class="ksr-icon__backer-badge"></span>
    2 backers
</p>
```

scrapy shell:

```
sites = sel.css(".reward__info")
for site in sites:
    a = site.xpath("./h2[@class='reward__pledge-amount']/text()").extract()
    b = site.xpath("./p[@class='reward__backer-count']/text()").extract()
    print a
    print b
    break
```

result:

```
[u'\nPledge $1 or more\n', u'\n']
[u'\n', u'\n2 backers\n']
```

As you can see,`text()`  return a list.
I thought it's because `<h2>` has a `<div>` in it, And `<p>` has a `<span>`
How can I only get the `text()`  under `<h2>` and `<p>`  without childnode text???

like:

```
[u'\nPledge $1 or more\n']
[u'\n2 backers\n']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `normalize-space()` in XPath predicate for `text()` to filter out empty text nodes, something like :

```py
a = site.xpath("./h2[@class='reward__pledge-amount']/text()[normalize-space()]").extract()
b = site.xpath("./p[@class='reward__backer-count']/text()[normalize-space()]").extract()
```